# AM64x Host mode issue

Tags: embedded, usb, usb-drive, usb-hostcontroller

I am working with the AM64x board. Check with the sample USB Host code. It does not initialize properly when something is plugged into the port on bootup.
The USB device I am trying to use draws only a small current. Connect the phone it get charged.

I don't really understand what this error is, or how to correct it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to have some chance of getting in order, please provide more information. Show your code. Be specific about the board. Describe in detail what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i need information about how to check the usb pin initialization in am64x board. How to set the USB_DM?